# Referencing a range on another sheet in vba code to copy a formula down to the last row of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with two sheets.  On sheet1 I have a column (A) for which I need to copy the formula in A2 down for as many rows as there are in sheet2 column (B).Currently I use the following code

```
Range("B3:B" & Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = Range ("B2")
```

to do something similar but where the range referred to is on the same worksheet.  What I need to know is how to adapt this code to replace the "C" above with the range on sheet 2.  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
With Sheet1 ' reference Sheet1 worksheet
    .Range("B3:B" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = .Range("B2").Formula
End With
```

to copy sheet1 cell B2 formula down as many rows as Sheet2 column B last not empty cell row index

Answer (score 0):

For **every** `Range()`, `Cells()`, `Rows()` and `Columns()` object specify in which sheet they are. Don't miss any of them or your code can randomly fail.

Example

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")  'addresses cell A1 in Sheet1
```

You can use variables as references:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range("A1") 'now also addresses cell A1 in Sheet1
```

while

```
Range("A1")
```

will address the sheet that has focus (is on top) while the code runs. Don't rely on this because this can easily change by a single mouse click of the user. Therefore always specify which sheet you mean.

Comment: Thank you.  I have added the variable as described above but then got a Subscript out of range error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: "Subscript out of range" means either your range is not correct or the worksheet with that name does not exist. Please edit your original question and append the code you used there so we can see it. Or have a look at HTH's anwser.